# Critical parameter behind skimage's watershed "over-segmentation"

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image, watershed

I have the following mask of cell nuclei, and my goal is to segment them. However, using what seems to be a very standard approach,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from skimage.segmentation import watershed
from skimage import measure

# load mask
mask = mpimg.imread('mask.png')

# find distance to nearest border
distance = scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_edt(mask)

# find local maxima based on distance to border
local_maxi = peak_local_max(distance, indices=False, footprint=np.ones((125, 125)), labels=mask)

# generate markers for regions
markers = measure.label(local_maxi)

# watershed segmentation
labeled = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=mask, watershed_line = True)

# plot figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.imshow(labeled, cmap='flag')
```

some large, connected components are unsegmented while smaller unconnected components become oversegmented:

[image: Input mask]
[image]

Throughly browosing answers on StackOverflow, I haven't been able to find is a discussion of which parameters drive 'under-segmentation' vs 'over-segmentation' in the `skimage.segmentation.watershed` algorithm.

**Which parameter most strongly influences "oversegmentation" in the watershed algorithm**? My intuition tells me it could be the footprint size? or the distance transform? What is the most critical parameter that determines the segmentation neighbourhood?

EDIT1: Below I have included the distance transform, the filtering of which others have pointed out is a critically important step. However, I am still unable to diagnose symptoms of a "bad" distance transform, and unaware of rules of thumbs for filtering said transform.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, which parameters? You have only one parameter in your code: `footprint=np.ones((125, 125))`. I’m surprised you get those results with such a large region though.

Comment: I have seen some discussion of (a) using different distance metrics to calculate the distance from non-background point to the nearest zero (b) different "shapes" (ie. a circular mask) for footprints to find local maximas. I would consider parameters as that directly passed to ```watershed``` as well as anything upstream.

Comment: Rather than take a large footprint in the local maxima detection, you should filter the distance transform to remove irrelevant local maxima. The H-maxima filter is typically used for this. Works well. You can also use a Gaussian filter, it’s not as good in this case, but can be useful in certain circumstances. Don’t change to a different distance measure, your cells are round, not square.

Comment: I see. To extend an idea you mentioned earlier, would it be more prudent to break the images into smaller portions, find local maxima for each area, concatenate, and then perform watershed?

Comment: No, I would not split up the image, how do you know how to split the image such that there’s only one object in each section? I would filter the distance transform, detect local maxima (`skimage.morphology.local_maxima`), then apply the watershed. It’s all in how you filter the distance transform.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, although it is unclear to me how best to threshold the distance transform. What are some symptoms of a bad transform, and what are some rules of thumbs for filtering?

Comment: Multiple local maxima within the same object is bad. You have to avoid those. The H-maxima transform is the best filter. But note that skimage’s `h_maxima` seems to be the H-maxima transform followed by `local_maxima`, it does both steps in one.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, the origin of some of your over-segmentation is on the result of peak_local_max().

If you run the following code you will be able to find which local maximums are selected for your image. I'm using OpenCV for plotting dots, you might want to adapt it for another library.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
localMax_idx = np.where(local_maxi)
    
localMax_img = mask.copy()
localMax_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for i in range(localMax_idx[0].shape[0]):
    x = localMax_idx[1][i]
    y = localMax_idx[0][i]
    localMax_img = cv2.circle(localMax_img, (x,y), radius=5, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=-1)

plt.imshow(localMax_img)
plt.show()
```

You will see that there are multiple markers for over-segmented cells. There are some suggested approaches to deal with this issue (for example, [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1746809419301491)).